# Extend this solution for high dimensional matrices in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

My original goal was to do some jugglery with a couple of matrices. Its simple and I explaine it for 2D matrices below:

Given a certain matrix Matrix1 as:

[image]

, and a binary matrix Matrix2 as this:

[image]

, I want to allocate the elements from Matrix1 to Matrix2 such that I have a final matrix Matrix3, which looks like:

[image]

The following one liner worked for me:

`(Matrix3 = zeros(eltype(Matrix1),size(Matrix2)))'[Matrix2'[:]] .= Matrix1'[:]`

Now I need to extend it for higher dimensions i.e. 3D or more. So, suppose Matrix1 has dimension (4,6,6) and the binary matrix Matrix2 has dimension (4,12,12). The allocation problem remains the same. How would then you approach it? Can someone kindly help me in it (preferably with a one liner)? Note here that for both the matrices the size of the first dimension is the same here, 4 in this case. Along the rest of the two dimensions, individually both the matrices are square.